# STL class for reference-counted pointers?

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers, reference-counting

This should be trivial but I can't seem to find it (unless no such class exists!)

What's the STL class (or set of classes) for smart pointers?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the responses,
I must say I'm surprised there's no standard implementation.

I ended up using this one: http://archive.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1060.asp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the exception of the already mentionned TR1 shared_ptr, there is no reference-counted pointer in STL.

I suggest you use boost::shared_ptr (downloading boost will be enough, there is nothing to compile, its implementation is header-only).

You may also want to have a look at smart pointers from Loki libraries (again, header-only implementation).

For an overview of available smart pointers, see [there](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403837).

Comment: boost::shared_ptr was the inspiration for std::tr1::shared_ptr.  Subsequently std::tr1::shared_ptr becomes std::shared_ptr in C++0x.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want/can't use Boost **and** your compiler implements [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1), you can use `shared_ptr` (borrowed from Boost):

```
#include <tr1/memory>

...

std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo);
```

Otherwise, no, there are no smart pointers except `std::auto_ptr` in vanilla STL.

Answer (score 3):

Time marches on, in C++11:

```
std::shared_ptr
std::weak_ptr
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

For COM objects, use [CComPtr<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98(vs.80).aspx).

Comment: CComPtr isn't reference counted -- the underlying object itself is.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative implemented for some time in STL PLUS, see at [source forge](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/smart_ptr.html)

`"STLplus was originally intended as a library to extend the STL by providing missing container data structures such as smart-pointers, matrices, trees and graphs."`