# In C++ How do references and pointers in parameters actually work? What are their set-in-stone protocol/"rule"?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Say you have

`void foo(int a, int &b, int *c){...}`

```
int main(){
   int d=0, e=1, f=2;
   foo(d, e, &f);
}
```

It is my understanding that the function declaration parameters must have the same type as the argument. Hence the "int" in front of a, b, and c because d, e, and f are all ints.

But does this extend (also apply) to the references and pointers, i.e. `&` and `*`? 
What I mean is, if you have `int &b`, does `e` have to be an address already?

I thought it did, but now I think I have the concept wrong after reading this thread:
[C++ functions: ampersand vs asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670101/c-functions-ampersand-vs-asterisk)
in which the code outlined in is pretty much what I have written above.

After reading the thread and the code above, it seems that the `&` and `*` in the parameter is actually not part of the "type restriction" -- i.e. it does not mean that e has to be an address, or that f has to be a pointer.

See previously **I thought** that whatever proceeded the paramater names `a, b, c` in the parameter was *strictly specifying what type it must be*

so you would code something like this:

```
void foo(int a, int &b, int *c){...}

int main(){
   int d=0, e=1, f=2;
   foo(d, &e, *f); // wrong 
}
```

Instead, it seems that the `&` in the parameter actually takes the variabe/object argument that is passed in and CHANGES or GETS its address. And the `*` is actually ACTING UPON the address of f (`&f`) which is passed as an argument and retrieving it's contents. Is this right?

Is this just the given protocol/rule for `&` and `*` placed in the parameter that one must accept?

I've read up on many articles regarding references and pointers in parameters, and they all explain  very clearly  that the `&` and `*` in the parameter allows one to change the value of the variable passed. However, they never go very deep into the actual procedure/protocol of the `&` and `*` when placed in the parameter.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Let me know if I have this conceptually right.
Thank you!

Comment: No, the two different uses of `&` put you off. In the first line, `&` means that the variable will be passed by reference. In the call, the `&` does mean the address of `f`. Not the same thing. (Well, they're related of course, but they have different semantic meanings.)

Comment: I think you are confused about syntax and the difference meanings of `&` and `*` in different contexts. `int* c` means `pointer to an int`. `*f` means "de-reference whatever f is`.

Comment: Oh, and _"It is my understanding that the function declaration parameters must have the same type as the argument. "_ but this is not entirely true, it's not a _must_. You can have a `float` for an argument and call it with an `int`.

Comment: You can NOT, however, have a `float&` for an argument and call it with and `int`!

Comment: @MrLister At your first comment: Yeah I think I understood the differences of &. So I guess in a way you are saying that if you have & in the first line (param), then it is simply a matter of protocol that the address of a variable/object is retrieved?

Comment: @juanchopanza and I guess that the "pointer to an int" part simply means I have to pass an address because pointers need to hold an address? I guess I'm just over-thinking this maybe and somewhat answering my own q.

Comment: @Gnuey Strictly speaking, you don't have to _know_ that `int&` means the address is passed. It does work that way, under the hood; so that the address of `b` inside the function is the same as the address of `e` in main. But that's not the issue; the essence is that `e` is passed _by reference_, which means you can change `b` in the function and `e` will then be changed after the call. That's how you should treat reference parameters. If you do want to work with their addresses, using pointers makes more sense.

Comment: @Gnuey and yes, pointers hold addresses, and that's all they can hold. No overthinking there. They're very powerful though, they can also hold addresses of other pointers or addresses of functions. Lovely stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The doubt arises because in C++ the same operator is used for different purposes in different contexts. For example the following operators have different meaning in different situations.

The operator `&` can mean `address-of` a variable or a `reference` to a variable. For example consider the following code,

```
int *ptr;    
int n=111;    
ptr=&n;
```

In the above code the operator `&` gets the address of the variable    `n`.

Now consider the code shown below,

```
   int a=111;    
   int &ref = a;
```

Here `&` is used to create a reference to the variable `a`. You can    use the variable ref to access the variable a.

The operator `*` can be used to create  a  pointer variable or  to fetch the content of a variable. For example consider the following code,

```
int *ptr;
```

In the above code the operator `*`  is used to declare `ptr` as a pointer variable.

Now consider the code shown below,

```
int a=111,b;    
int *ptr = &a;
b=*ptr;
```

Here `*ptr` is used to fetch the content of `a`.

There are other operator also in C++ with different meaning in different contexts, for example,

The operator `+` can be a unary or binary opearator. For example `+` is
   a binary operator in the expression `c=a+b;` and a unary operator in the expression `b=+a;`

The operator `-` can be a unary or binary opearator. For example `-` is
   a binary operator in the expression `c=a-b;` and a unary operator in
   the expression `b=-a;`

Comment: Hmm, nice I guess there was a subtle difference there in the `int &ref* example I didn't catch. Also, how can `*a` fetch the contents of `a` if a is never an address? Did you mean to write `*ptr` is used to fetch `a`?

Comment: +1 nice answer! Worth pointing out that the technical name of "fetching" the contents of the pointer e.g `b=*ptr;` (so putting the asterisk preceding the pointer variable when assigning it to a non-pointer type) is known as **dereferencing**.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly think you need to open some book and go through it at least once. Ampersand (&) and asterisk (*) does same thing but it’s just that they look different and they do their stuff differently.

To start,

Pointers, as you know are data types that stores address, i.e. its purpose is to point to another variables..

References - two things about them.
1). References are nothing but just another name for the objects/variables to which they are referring to.
2). References has been introduced to overcome the untidy and complex syntax of pointers. See the declaration and usage of both,

```
int  num = 45;
int* ptr = &num;
int& ref = num;
```

both ptr and ref is pointing to num. please notice their syntax and also the way they dereference the value.

```
cout<<*ptr;
cout<<ref;
```

Now you can see yourself, what the difference is and what looks cleaner...

-Bhupesh

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable that holds an address to something. A reference is really a pointer with a nice package and plenty of sugar in the picture to make it look tasty. Inside, once you open it up, it does the same thing.

When they put the nice packaging around pointers to make references, they did make it a little safer in that a reference can't be `NULL`, so you don't have to check if someone used "NULL" as the input when using a reference - pointers can be `NULL`, so you have to check for that first [or don't, but then it may crash - which is not very good...].

The nice packaging means the compiler knows to pass an address for a reference, where if you have a pointer, you have to make sure it's an address passed in - either by using a pointer variable as the parameter, or using the address-of operator.

I'm sure the reason they used the `&` for "this is a reference" is related to the fact that "where passing an address here, but you don't need to do anything when passing the variable to the function, the compiler will fix it up for you".

When you declared a pointer, you use `*` - this applies both for variables and arguments to functions.

In other places `&` means "the address of" something (make this into a pointer), and `*` means "what this pointer points to". Again, the nice packaging means the `*` is hidden from view when using references, but the compiler will do those things for you.

Comment: Ah. That is a sweet way to put it. That's helpful for seeing things from the language side.